# Regexp for extensions tgz, tar.gz, TGZ and TAR.GZ

Tags: regex, bash

Im trying to get a regexp (in bash) to identify files with only the following extensions : 
    tgz, tar.gz, TGZ and TAR.GZ.
    I tried several ones but cant get it to work.
    Im using this regexp to select only files files with those extensions to do some work with them :

```
if [ -f $myregexp ]; then

  .....                                                                                       
fi
```

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# no case match 
shopt -s nocasematch
matchRegex='.*\.(tgz$)|(tar\.gz$)'
for f in *
do
    # display filtered files   
    [[ -f "$f" ]] && [[ "$f" =~ "$matchRegex"  ]] &&  echo "$f";

done
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found an elegant way of doing this:

```
shopt -s nocasematch
for file in *; 
do 
 [[ "$file" =~ .*\.(tar.gz|tgz)$ ]] && echo $file
done
```

This may be good for you since you seems to want to use the if and a bash regex. The `=~` operator allow to check if the pattern is matching a given expression. Also `shopt -s nocasematch` has to be set to perfom a case insensitive match.

Answer (score 0):

Write 4 regexes, and check whether the file name matches any of them. Or write 2 case-insensitive regexes.

This way the code will be much more readable (and easier) than writing 1 regex.

Comment: One case-insensitive regex is enough.

Comment: isnt it possible with just one regexp , and if not how can i make a regex case-insensitive ? , thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Use this pattern

```
 .*\.{1}(tgz|tar\.gz)
```

But how to make a regular expression case-insensitive? It depends on the language you use. In JavaScript they use `/pattern/i`, in which, `i` denotes that the search should be case-insensitive. In C# they use RegexOptions enumeration.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on where you want to use this regex. If with GREP, then use `egrep` with -i parameter, which stands for "ignore case"

```
egrep -i "(\.tgz)|(\.tar\.gz)$"
```

Comment: actually im using it to select only files with those extensions (as in if [ -f $myregex ]; then .. .

Answer (score 0):

You can even do it without a regex (a bit wordy though):

```
for f in *.[Tt][Gg][Zz] *.[Tt][Aa][Rr].[Gg][Zz]; do
   echo $f
done
```

Answer (score 0):

In bash? Use curly brackets, *.{tar.gz,tgz,TAR.GZ,TGZ} or even *.{t{ar.,}gz,T{AR.,}GZ}. Thus, ls -l *.{t{ar.,}gz,T{AR.,}GZ} on the command-line will do a detailed listing of all files with the matching extensions.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."